# SparkSQL splitting a string on the first occurrence of a string

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a String column called `field` in a spark DataFrame that looks like this:

> my_field_name:abc_def_ghi

I want to strip off the `my_field_name` part and just be left with the value. Normally I'd use a udf and use substring functions, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this using the SparkSQL functions so that I don't incur additional SerDe in serializing the udf. Here's my attempt:

```
.withColumn("fieldVals", split(substring($"field", instr($"field", "?"), len($"field")), ""))
```

The problem is that `split` expects an `Int`, and I'm giving it an `Int` `Column` instead. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Using `regexp_extract`:

```scala
val df = Seq("my_field_name:abc_def_ghi").toDF("field")
df.select(regexp_extract($"field", ":(.*)", 1) as "col").show()
```

Output:

```
+-----------+
|        col|
+-----------+
|abc_def_ghi|
+-----------+
```

Or alternatively using `substring_index`:

```scala
df.select(substring_index($"field", ":", -1) as "col").show()
```

or `split`:

```scala
df.select(split($"field", ":").getItem(1) as "col").show()
```

Comment: Oh cool! Can this extract multiple pieces at a time? say I wanted to split the result by `_`, so there would be 3 columns `abc`, `def`, `ghi`

Comment: That's probably easiest to handle with `split` `Seq("abc_def_ghi").toDF("field").select(split($"field", "_") as "tmp").select($"tmp".getItem(0), $"tmp".getItem(1), $"tmp".getItem(2))` . Regex would work as well if you need more complicated logic